# Kindle "Time Left in Book"

Tags: kindle-paperwhite

I have a Paperwhite, and I like to have 'percentage left' on the page as I am reading.  To switch this on, I have to go to Font size and select from a pull-down menu.  Once the Kindle switches off, I have to reset that when I start again.

Is there any way of making the 'percentage left' or 'time left in book' as a default?

Answer (score 2):

When in a book, tapping in the very bottom left of the screen will rotate through LOC, Page, Time left in Chapter, Time left in Book, and off. When in any mode other than off, the percent completion will appear in the bottom right of the screen.

This is based on a 7th gen Paperwhite with firmware version 5.11.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

What firmware version are you running? because on my Paperwhite (3rd gen) version 5.8.7.0.1 I have percentage always displayed in the bottom right. And time left displayed on the left

Answer (score -1):

You can tap on it to change it to display Time Left in the Chapter,Time left in the book & LOC.